# Python Two Lists from One list with Tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, python-2.x

I have a list:

```
data = ['Other stuff',186.797\t-48',
 '187.272\t-48',
 '187.747\t-48',
 '188.222\t-45',
 '188.697\t-43',
 '189.172\t6',
 '189.646\t-23',
 '190.121\t12',...]
```

How do I create two lists one with value before the "/t" and another with the value afterwards.

However, I only want to do this from data[1] to len(data) skipping the first value because it is just descriptive text.

For example:

```
L1 = [186.797,...,190.121]
L2 = [-48,..., 12]
```

Comment: Is this an improperly parsed TSV?

Comment: The program I used to produce the values just spit out the data.
The left side is wavelength while the right side is time.
I am just not sure how to make it into two lists in python since the length of each value is different.

Comment: `L1, L2  = zip(*(s.split('\t') for s in data))` will get you there...

Comment: Or even, `L1, L2 = zip(*map(str.split, data))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
import re
s = ['186.797\t-48',
 '187.272\t-48',
 '187.747\t-48',
 '188.222\t-45',
 '188.697\t-43',
 '189.172\t6',
 '189.646\t-23',
 '190.121\t12']

L1, L2 = map(list, zip(*[[float(re.findall('[\d\.]+', i)[0]), int(re.findall('[\-\d]+$', i)[0])] for i in s]))
```

Output:

```
[186.797, 187.272, 187.747, 188.222, 188.697, 189.172, 189.646, 190.121]
[-48, -48, -48, -45, -43, 6, -23, 12]
```

Comment: Why the need for all the regex?

Comment: @pstatix It has been a while, but in hindsight I would probably use a `str.split` or singe `re.split`. However, the `re.findall`'s make it a little easier to `zip` the resulting columns.

Answer (score 1):

An easy, clear way would be to use list comprehension and describe where you want to get all the data from. You can use `.split("\t")` to break each element into a tuple with two values, split by the tab. Then use `float` and `int` to convert the element you want.

```
# Iterate over the list and grab everything before the \t and convert to a float
L1 = [float(val.split("\t")[0]) for val in values]
#: [186.797, 187.272, 187.747, 188.222, 188.697, 189.172, 189.646, 190.121]

# Iterate over the list and grab everything after the \t and convert to an int
L2 = [int(val.split("\t")[1]) for val in values]
#: [-48, -48, -48, -45, -43, 6, -23, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and separate the values using `.split()`

```
l = ['186.797\t-48', '187.272\t-48', '187.747\t-48', '189.172\t6']

[x.split('\t')[0] for x in l]
['186.797', '187.272', '187.747', '189.172']

[x.split('\t')[1] for x in l]
['-48', '-48', '-48', '6']
```

Edit: If you need number values in your new lists then cast the values to `float()` or `int()`

```
l = ['186.797\t-48', '187.272\t-48', '187.747\t-48', '189.172\t6']

[float(x.split('\t')[0]) for x in l]
[186.797, 187.272, 187.747, 189.172]

[int(x.split('\t')[1]) for x in l]
[-48, -48, -48, 6]
```

Comment: I think Brian wants the output to be integers

Comment: Yeah, his question doesn't have any quotes